# jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE definition grails

Tags: grails, h2

What's definition or sintax of

```
jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

i understand:

> jdbc:(this is a database admin, h2, mysql, sql, etc.)
>
> mem: is the location
>
> devDb is the name of file
>
> MVCC...(and others) I no have idea

but which is really the definition?

Comment: Please mark the question as answered :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the JDBC connection string for an in-memory H2 database. You can see the various options available [in the H2 docs](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url)

Comment: Still no explanation on what is MVCC though, here is the documentation on MVCC: http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#mvcc